# Badges and tag "X" buttons misplaced

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

While I only have one badge, it is appearing incorrectly on meta:

[image: Badge]

[image: Badge 2]

[image: Badge 3]

While I was reporting this bug, I noticed that the "X" button that appears in the tag field is misplaced as well:

[image: Tags]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting it. There was some issue with our SVG sprite file for icons. For some reason it was off by few pixels - probably there was some issue with file export.

Anyway, fix for this is now in repo waiting for build. Should be up in few hours.

(fyi: I'm one of designers working in Stack Overflow sorry if that wasn't clear)